# Не подключается подключить jQuery к html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется вот такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="" src="script2.js"></script>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My page</h1>
    <h2>My page2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

и такой код в файле script2.js:

```
$('h2').css({'color':'red'});
alert('hello');
```

Алерты работают, значит сам файл js я подключил правильно. А вот код jQuery -- нет. Похожий код я использовал в своем другом проекте, и там все нормально работало.

Comment: А какая ошибка в консоли?

Comment: сообщений об ошибках никаких нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам весь jquery код нужно помещать внутрь $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h2').css({'color':'red'});
    alert('hello');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="" src="script2.js"></script>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My page</h1>
    <h2>My page2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Код действительно работает, но вопрос(может он и будет казаться банальным и глупым), почему раньше при использовании jQuery я мог пренебрегать данной функцией и весь год нормально работал.

Comment: @Тимур *раньше при использовании jQuery я писал весь год, который не покажу, и он нормально работал. Объясните - почему. Время пошло.*

Comment: @Тимур использовать jquery без данной функции можно, например добавлять ее в тег кнопок onclick или использовать в функциях которые будут вызываться после загрузки страницы

Answer (score 1):

Или поместить `<script type="" src="script2.js"></script>` в конец, перед `</body>`

Answer (score 1):

**Порядок выполнения обычных (не module, не defer, не async) скриптов в HTML седующий:**

- Приостанавливается парсинг HTML.
- Блокируется событие DOMContentLoaded.
- Скрипт сразу подгружается, парсится и выполняется.
- Гарантируется порядок выполнения относительно других обычных скриптов.

Учитывая вышесказанное, когда браузер встретил ваш скрипт, то пока он не выполнит его, он не отпарсит часть страницы под ним. В то время, когда он выполняется - ваших тегов **H1** и **H2** еще не существует. Скрипт работает нормально, но jQuery не делает ничего!

Вам нужно **догрузить/дорендерить** всю станицу, а уже потом, делать с ней что-либо. **jQuery рекомендует это делать следующим образом:**

```
$(function() {

  $('h2').css({'color':'red'});
  alert('hello');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать следующую структуру для подключаемого файла **script2.js**

```
!function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // ТУТ ВАШ КОД
  });
}(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

$

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $('h2').css({'color':'red'});
    alert('hello');
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="" src="script2.js"></script>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My page</h1>
    <h2>My page2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]